# jquery, margin-top depending of $(window).height()

Tags: jquery, css

i have a div-container and its top-margin should be set as a dependency of $(window).height(), so first i tried something like this:

```
        $("div#outerstart").css("margin-top",$(window).height() -805+"px");
```

it worked fine, but the margin-top should never be a negative, so i tried this:

```
        $("div#outerstart").css("margin-top",function () {
        if ($(window).height() < 805) {
            0+"px"  
        } else {
            $(window).height() -805+"px"
        }
    });
```

or also

```
 if ($(window).height() < $(document).height()) {...
```

but it shows no effect and margin-top is not set. do you have any suggestions?

Comment: use return keyword? its function, not direct declaration

Comment: @Marek Sebera: Write an answer instead of a comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

let's change your code to use `return` keyword from function

```
$("div#outerstart").css("margin-top",function () {
    if ($(window).height() < 805) {
        return "0px";  
    } else {
        return ($(window).height() -805)+"px";
    }
});
```

Comment: glad to help you, if my answer is correct, use green ticker on left side of answer. that's how things work here

Comment: you could remove the else block by changing `<` to `>` ... :p

Answer (score 3):

A simpler solution would be to use `Math.max` instead of the anonymous function:

```
$("div#outerstart").css("margin-top", Math.max(0, $(window).height()-805)+"px");
```